# Scala: How do I get this toy covariant example to work?

Tags: scala, covariance

Simple Covariance Example: why does asInstance work?

```
 class Fruit(name: String) { def get_name = name}
 class Apple(name: String)  extends Fruit(name)
 class Orange(name: String) extends Fruit(name)
 class BigOrange(name:String) extends Orange(name)

  // Contrived but simple covariant box with some utility functions
  class Box[+T <: Fruit] {
   def foo[ U >: T] (item: U): String = item.asInstanceOf[T].get_name 
  }

  val f = new Fruit("fruit")
  val a = new Apple("apple")
  val o = new Orange("orange")

  // Error. Makes sense apples cannot be casted to oranges
  println( a.asInstanceOf[Orange]) 


  val bo1 = new Box[Orange]
  println(bo1.foo(a)) // Returns Apple ! How was an apple seemingly casted to an orange?
```

So why does the last line work ? Isn't the  logic asking the passed apple to be casted to an orange?

A second question: Why does this code give me get_name not recognized error ?

```
class Box[+T <: Fruit] (item: T) {
  val contents = item
  def foo[ U >: T] (item: U): String = item.get_name
}
```

Between the [+T <: Fruit] and  U >: T, is'nt it obvious that item should have a get_name? why the error?

Comment: When you run into the need to use `asInstanceOf`, that is usually an indication that you are doing something wrong. The way `foo` is declared, you can call it like `foo(1200)` for example, or `foo("bar")`. I doubt that's what you want ... But what _is it_ that you actually want? What exactly are you trying to do here? For example, why not just `def foo(item: T) = item.get_name` to begin with?

Comment: I am trying to learn by asking myself why something works.  No, foo(120) does not work

Comment: By "works" I mean, it compiles. The type parameter is useless, this function will accept a parameter of any time, and then throw exceptions at runtime. 
Scala is a strictly-typed language, this is not at all how it is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Between the [+T <: Fruit] and U >: T, is'nt it obvious that item should have a get_name?

Of course it isn't. For example, `U = Any` satisfies the constraint and doesn't have `get_name` member.

Comment: 1. Is there a way of constraining along the lines of U >:T  _and_ U != Any _and_ U <: Fruit? if that, could it be in the future?

Comment: You can combine `U >: T` and `U <: Fruit`: `U <: Fruit >: T`. And `U <: Fruit` already implies `U != Any`.

Answer (score 1):

`asInstanceOf[T]` actually does nothing because type `T` of `Box` is erased. You also should get a warning from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here ...

```
class Box[+T <: Fruit] (item: T) {
  val contents = item
  def foo[U >: T] (item: U): String = item.get_name
}
```

... is that you're shadowing one `item` with another.  The 1st, `item: T`, *does* have a `get_name` member that the compiler can recognize, but the 2nd, `item: U`, doesn't. It could be a parent or superclass of `Fruit` which means there is no guarantee of a `get_name` member.